# NETSUITE - Custom Search - Criteria

Tags: netsuite

i am new to Netsuite and custom seraches, and need some help.
I am creating a new custom search in Netsuite, to be viewed under the Project details.
The view basically shows some data aggregation of timings and resource assignment. I also added a Criteria in order to let the user select a target project. What i would like to do, is to automatically set the search criteria for the "current project" when using the view in the Project Details form. can anybody help me? I tried to search for a while, but i cannot see, under criteria definition, a variable like "selected project".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and thanks everyone for replying. It came out that the issue was trying to set up a criteria to put in place the filter.
Once removed the criteria, opening the view from a project actually did the trick.
What mislead me was that while previewing the results, i was able to see every project. That's why i added the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

In the Available Filters subtab of your saved search, add Project as the first filter.
You can find more details under "Saved Searches for Custom Sublists" in the Help Center.

Comment: Hi, and thank you.I did this as one of the first things. Indeed, it seemed to me it would've worked. But if i change project, the view still have the filter setup up with my previous project. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your saved search?

Comment: Hi Jala, problem solved. I just posted the solution.